# How do you record the first time setup of an Android device without USB Debugging enabled?

Tags: adb, samsung, usb-debugging, screen-mirroring

I'm trying to record the initial setup of an Android phone/tablet for my company but i'm running into an issue where none of the Android to PC mirroring programs work during this part without having USB Debugging enabled. The problem is that these settings are not available because of the company settings and even then trying it on a private Android device it seems that when you Factory Reset the device the enabled USB Debugging setting is reset to its default which is off.

So my question is how do people take pictures or recordings of the initial Android setup with this conundrum in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Robert's suggestion of taking a screenshot helped. I used screenshot key combination Power + Volume down button wherever I needed to take screenshots during device setup. Those screenshtos were saved to the Gallery.